# Need advice, azure database or api approach

Tags: c#, azure

I'm developing some software that need to be in sync with a central database on cloud (azure), the thing is, I don't know if I need to build an web api to stay in sync with my database or can I use a direct connection with it.

If I choose to use a direct database approach I know that I need to add my ip address to the azure firewall but how can I automatizate this process without intervention of my self typing the azure credentials every time the IP changes.

My ideal scenario is the database direct connection but the constantly firewall rule on the database makes me wonder.

Regards,

Comment: Unfortunatly this is something that you would need to work out on your own based on your company requirements and any regs you need to follow. This will also attract many opinion based answers which although may be technically sound for their needs it might not fit your scenario.  I suggest, and (my opinion) is that you weigh up your options, what is the benefit of each option, and what is the drawback of each too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are about to connect to Azure SQL Database directly , just create a firewall rule for your local IP, and each time you want to connect to your Azure SQL , update that firewall rule with the value of your local IP via codes first . For instance , you can use Azure Powershell to update Azure SQL Database Firewall rule:

```
$username = "<azure account name>"
$passwd = "<azure account pass>"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $passwd -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $secpasswd)
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred -TenantId "<tenant ID>" -Subscription "<azure subscription ID>"

Set-AzureRmSqlServerFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName "<resource group name>" -ServerName "<Azure SQL server name>" -FirewallRuleName "<firewall rule name>" -StartIpAddress "<your local ip>" -EndIpAddress "<your local ip>"
```